# scandir for files for users

Tags: php, foreach, scandir

I've created a pages dashboard for my content management system, and well I am trying to iterate the `scandir` method and my conditions are not working. Can someone explain why?

```
$pages = scandir('../',0);
foreach($pages as $page){
  if($page !== "." OR $page !== ".." OR $page !== "admin" OR $page !== "admin.php" OR $page !== "kms_kontent" OR !is_dir('../'.$page)){
        $extension = explode('.',$page);
        $extension = end($extension);
        $page = str_replace('.'.$extension,'',$page);
     echo '<div class="row"><ul><li class="fifths">'.$page.'</li><li class="fifths"></li></ul></div>';
  }
}
```

It's echoing all contents

```
--public_html
   -admin.php #don't show
   -admin #don't show
   -kms_content #don'tshow
   -index.php #show
   -shop.php #show
```

Also it's showing `.` and `..` which I don't want to show either.

Comment: Inverted logic. Use `&&`.

Comment: Duh! I figured it would go through the condition testing each `OR` but `&&` works so I'm not going to argue!

Comment: You should use an array to simplify.

Comment: Hmm don't really see the logic to simplify that? It's literally all I'm testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is flawed. To see why, let's assume you have just this comparison:

```
$page !== "." OR $page !== ".."
```

The condition is satisfied if page isn't `.` or if page isn't `..`; if the page is `.` it will not be equal to `..` and vice versa. In other words, the condition is always satisfied.

What you want is that the condition is satisfied only if page is neither `.` nor `..`; so:

```
!($page === '.' || $page === '..')
```

Following DeMorgan's law:

```
$page !== '.' && $page !== '..'
```

An array of possible values could be used to simplify the code even more:

```
$invalid_pages = [".", "..", "admin", "admin.php", "kms_kontent"];

if (!in_array($page, $invalid_pages) && !is_dir('../'.$page)) {
}
```

Comment: Geesh only if there was a way to just tag you in all my questions, you seem to be able to satisfy what I am looking for when I come here which is not only an answer but as to why and actual understand. You've helped me understand! Always a pleasure @Jack

Answer (score 1):

```
if (
    $page !== "." OR
    $page !== ".." OR
    $page !== "admin" OR
    $page !== "admin.php" OR
    $page !== "kms_kontent" OR
    !is_dir('../'.$page)
) {
```

Because you are using `OR`, the if will go true when *any*  of the conditions is true. So if `$page` is `admin` it will go false for `$page !== "admin"` but true to all others, and it won't work. You should use `&&` or `AND`.

But instead, you could clean up that code a little bit using arrays. For instance:

```
$filter = ['.', '..', 'admin', 'admin.php', 'kms_kontent'];
$pages = scandir('../', 0);
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    if (!in_array($page, $filter) && !is_dir("../$page")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

It does the same thing, but the code looks cleaner and more items can be added more easily.

Comment: Never knew about the `in_array` function, especially since I am a JS developer and we have to write our own. Which I am ashamed since the same logic goes for JS and PHP conditions :/. Thanks Havenard

Comment: @EasyBB In JavaScript you can use `[].indexOf()` actually or the <your favourite library here>'s implementation :)

Comment: Well yes, but for compatibility actions I write a small inArray function. Which can pass multiple arguments. I hate libraries :D so I wouldn't know of a good library HAHA (there are none) just because they tend to everyones need and not just your current work load which can be a negative in return.

Answer (score 0):

Using AND or && instead of OR!

Comment: You are right, but when posting answers. What I look for is not just a simple answer, but a logical explanation. Take Jacks answer for example, it goes in depth. There are a lot of "Give Me this code" people out there, and I for one am not one. I like to learn and learn I do! But yes remember this when answering or most likely you'll get downvoted.